# Template inheritance conflict (multiple doLayout in the same page)

Tags: templates, inheritance, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a small problem with play-framwork (1.2.4).
I want to have a tag inherit another tag, and this one be included in a html page extending another web page. The best way to explain is with a schema :

[image: wanted architecture]

However, it did not work the way I want. In fact, the extends in the test.tag file seems to overwrite the one in Screen.html. Then, the content of all the Screen.html is included in the block.tag `#{doLayout /}` instead of in the one of main.html

Is there any way to do what I want ? 
Thanks.

---

Here is the sources :

*main.html*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
    <body>
    #{doLayout /}
    </body>
</html>
```

*Screen.html*

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
<div id="Screen.html">
    #{test  /}
</div>
```

*test.tag*

```
#{extends 'tags/block.tag' /}
test.tag
```

*block.tag*

```
<div id="test">
    #{doLayout /}
</div>
```

*The generated html when the page is called*

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="Screen.html">
        test.tag
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the main.html is not included and the the Screen is included in the block. Any ideas ?

---

For information, the wanted output :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
    <body>
        <div id="Screen.html">
            <div id="test">
                test.tag
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using #{extends /} in your templates but not use them in tags.

To have some more flexibility in building tags on top of another, you could do:

test.tag:

```
#{block }
test.tag
#{/block}
```

and block.tag:

```
<div id="test">
#{doBody /}
</div>
```

with this you are passing part of the body from a test.tag to a block.tag and inserting it somewhere in block.tag using #{doBody /}

Answer (score 0):

I think this might due to Groovy engine does `#{extends}` evaluation on runtime, the `screen.html` call `test.tag` which in turn extends `block.tag`, which happens after screen's extends to `main.html` and at runtime, groovy decide the final extends win.

Probably you want to try the [rythm plugin](http://www.playframework.com/modules/rythm) which evaluate `extends` semantic at parsing time. That says rythm has no issue in your case.